# Fail Continua CI build

Tags: build, continuous-integration, build-process

I have reviewed all the Continua CI staging actions, but can't find any to force build process to fail. "Stop" build action is just executed with "Success" state. Have I missed something?

**Update**
Continua CI server version is 1.5.0.338. This solution is not applicable http://wiki.finalbuilder.com/display/continua/Stop+Action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround using "Run DOS Command / Batch File" with command set to:

```
EXIT /B 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stop Action to fail a build, just uncheck the "As Success" option.

Comment: Forgot to mention in 1.5.0.338 version available only "Enabled" checkbox on this dialog, no "As Success" option present as in this guide http://wiki.finalbuilder.com/display/continua/Stop+Action

Comment: Not sure why you are not seeing the option, it's been there since before v1.0. Try updating to the latest version (1.5.1.x).

Comment: Updated, but still the same dialog with no this option appears

Comment: Note that the As Success option is only available if you select to stop the "Stage" from the drop-down list (as noted in the guide). 

If you select the "Build" option, this always stops the build as success. This option has never been there and is not required because when you stop the Stage with As Success unticked, this will fail the Stage **and** the Build. 

The text is a bit confusing and we plan update the action to make this clearer.